# статический интерфейс pptp подключения

Tags: linux, vpn

Есть pptp подключение Подключаю через: pppd call tunnel 
или через pptpsetup --create pptpd --server 111.111.111.111 --username loginr --password pass --encrypt --start

При подключении присваивается интерфейс ppp0 или ppp1 (если ppp0 уже занят). Долго гуглил и не нагуглил.

Как сделать, что бы определенный туннель всегда был под определенным интерфейсом(например ppp0 или ppp2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь параметром `unit номер` программы *pppd*.

из `man pppd`:

> **unit** num — Sets  the  ppp  unit  number (for a ppp0 or ppp1 etc interface name) for outbound connections.  If the unit is already in use a dynamically allocated number will be used.

вольный перевод:

> **unit** номер — установить номер «ppp-юнита» (для именования интерфейса: `ppp0`, `ppp1` и т.д.) для исходящих соединений. если «юнит» уже используется, будет выбран следующий свободный.

---

в случае установки соединения программой *pppd* можно прямо параметром указать:

```
$ sudo pppd unit 2 call tunnel ...
```

или добавить в этот самый файл `tunnel` (находящийся по умолчанию в каталоге `/etc/ppp/peers`).

---

в случае же установки соединения программой *pptpd* картина несколько сложнее: придётся воспользоваться файлом, в который следует добавить этот параметр. по умолчанию для параметров, передаваемых программе *pppd*, программа *pptpd* использует файл `/etc/ppp/options`, но имя этого файла можно подменить опцией `-o /путь/к/файлу`.

теоретически, можно попробовать обойтись без файла и воспользоваться файловым дескриптором, создаваемым оболочкой, так называемой «подстановкой процесса» (*process substitution*):

```
 $ pptpd -o <(echo "unit 3") ...
```

но у меня сейчас нет возможности проверить, «согласится» ли программа *pptpd* на файловый дескриптор вместо «живого» файла в этом месте.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо. Вы гений :)

Comment: @soulsoul, это просто [давний опыт](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=30016), последние лет десять уже практически бесполезный — туннели точка-точка встречаются «в живой природе» всё реже и реже.